# Update ng-model value in a modal dialog

Tags: angularjs

I have an application which uses AngularJS. I have a contact us page where in i populate the the name, email field based on the logged in user. Now lets say user updates his/her name or email from profile page and that should reflect in the contact us page. The contact us page is loaded as a **modal dialog**, and the updated value is not reflected until i reload the page.

Comment: Sir, you got some code too ?

Comment: From what I think, you could have two issues: 1/ you are not populating the fields with the same model as you're using in the profile page. 2/ Or, you're not correctly sending the updated value to the modal dialog scope. Now, more code from you could help.

Comment: Did you sort that out? Have you tested the provided solutions? Please update the status of the question

Answer (score 0):

The $modal.open{...}) returns an object which result property is a promise:

```
$modal.open({...}).result
```

is a promise. You can attach a success handler to update the data in the controller. When you close the modal whether using $modalInstance.close or $close in your HTML, do not forget to call it with the newUserName as argument.

```
function yourCtrl ($scope) {
    $scope.userName = // whatever

    $modal.open({...}).result.then(function (newUserName) {
        // update the userName:
        $scope.userName = newUserName;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say in Profile page...you have a modal....umm, say `$scope.name`. If you're triggering the Contact page modal dialog from inside the Profile page - meaning the Contact page is a child of the Profile page...in your html, you could say:

```
<xx>{{$parent.name}}</xx>
```

Makes sense?